# ThreadAbort on Using ASP.NET Identity Model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous, threadabortexception

I was following [this post on email confirmation](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/10/adding-email-confirmation-to-aspnet.html) except for ASP.NET. The following code is causing a

```
Exception Details: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException: Thread was being aborted.
```

The page is marked Async:

```
<%@ Page Title="Register" Async="true" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Register.aspx.cs" Inherits="AlphaFrontEndSiteASP.Account.Register" %>
```

The code is:

```
public partial class Register : Page
    {
        protected async void CreateUser_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                string confirmationToken = CreateConfirmationToken();
                var user = new ApplicationUser
                {
                    UserName = UserName.Text,
                    CompanyName = CompanyName.Text,
                    emailAddress = emailAddress.Text,
                    FirstName = FirstName.Text,
                    LastName = LastName.Text,
                    ConfirmationToken = confirmationToken,
                    IsConfirmed = false
                };

                var manager = new UserManager();
                var result = await manager.CreateAsync(user, Password.Text);
                if (result.Succeeded)
                {
                    SendEmailConfirmation(emailAddress.Text, UserName.Text, confirmationToken);
                }
                Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                common c = new common();
                c.LogError(ex.Message, "Register.aspx.cs" + " - " + this.GetType().FullName + "." + System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name);
            }

 private string CreateConfirmationToken()
        {
            return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        }

        private void SendEmailConfirmation(string to, string username, string confirmationToken)
        {
            common c = new common();
            c.SendMail("foo@foo.net", to, username, confirmationToken + Environment.NewLine + "http://blah.com/Activate.aspx?confirmationCode= " + confirmationToken);
        }
```

Does anyone have any ideas why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By design - [Response.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9dwyts4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) stops request processing by aborting the thread:

> Redirect calls End which throws a ThreadAbortException exception upon completion.

```
  ....
  Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
```

Depending on you other processing you can either

- specify `false` as second argument of other [Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a8wa7sdt%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) override
- ignore/no log `ThreadAbortException` in that piece of code
- redesign code to do redirect differently.

Note: if you use ASP.Net MVC it's [Controller.Redirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirect%28v=vs.118%29.aspx) does not throw exception.